# Why is my header format applying to all cells when I insert to excel file from SSIS

Tags: microsoft-excel, ssis

I am using SSIS to export a sql query to a pre formatted template excel file. The template file has the header row formatted with text wrapping, and the rest of the rows normal formatting. I want the data to insert with normal formatting, when it inserts, every row has text wrapping.

Comment: Maybe the data you copy is already formatted with text wrapping?

Comment: No, the data comes directly from a sql database.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Excel was automatically wrapping text where the cell value didn't fit the cell width rather than hiding the text.